# Can "missing section headers" ELF files still be executed/dangerous?

Tags: elf, file-format, executable

On VirusTotal, there are lots of ELF samples are `missing section headers` when using `file` command to see the info.

Also, when using the Python `elftools` library to parse them, exceptions will be thrown.

Can these kinds of ELF files still be executed or dangerous?
If so, what's the best way to parse them?

Example:
https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/7096d1deb8a097b25a74cb2b72009dc37430180b53725e1bec4d18be5856f139/detection
(This is not a good example as it's a ".so" file.)

---

Add the real output:

readelf -h:

```
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 02 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  Class:                             ELF32
  Data:                              2's complement, big endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              EXEC (Executable file)
  Machine:                           IBM S/390
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x403650
  Start of program headers:          52 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          1090000 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x0
  Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           32 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         8
  Size of section headers:           40 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         27
  Section header string table index: 26
readelf: Error: Reading 0x438 bytes extends past end of file for section headers
```

readelf -l:

```
readelf: Error: Reading 0x438 bytes extends past end of file for section headers

Elf file type is EXEC (Executable file)
Entry point 0x403650
There are 8 program headers, starting at offset 52

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr   PhysAddr   FileSiz MemSiz  Flg Align
  PHDR           0x000034 0x00400034 0x00400034 0x00100 0x00100 R E 0x4
  INTERP         0x000134 0x00400134 0x00400134 0x0000d 0x0000d R   0x1
  [Requesting program interpreter: /lib/ld.so.1]
  LOAD           0x000000 0x00400000 0x00400000 0xd7c70 0xd7c70 R E 0x1000
  LOAD           0x0d7c70 0x004d8c70 0x004d8c70 0x2da34 0x3167c RW  0x1000
  DYNAMIC        0x1052a8 0x005062a8 0x005062a8 0x000e0 0x000e0 RW  0x4
  NOTE           0x000144 0x00400144 0x00400144 0x00020 0x00020 R   0x4
  GNU_EH_FRAME   0x0d7b7c 0x004d7b7c 0x004d7b7c 0x0002c 0x0002c R   0x4
  GNU_STACK      0x000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000 0x00000 RW  0x4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Section information is not used at all when the kernel loads a program into memory to create its process image. In other words, execution in no way depends on section information.
- Stripping section information from a binary is not in and of itself necessarily an indicator of dangerous/criminal functionality, although it can serve to make analysis more difficult.
- According to VirusTotal, the example binary you linked to contains 29 sections, so I am not sure what that is supposed to be an example of. Perhaps one of the fields in the ELF header having to do with sections has been edited/corrupted to slow down automatic analysis, since section information cannot be displayed.

  - if the section header table is still present in the binary, the ELF header can be repaired so that this information is properly parsed. See [here](https://binaryresearch.github.io/2020/01/15/Analyzing-ELF-Binaries-with-Malformed-Headers-Part-3-Solving-A-Corrupted-Keygenme.html) for an example
  - run `readelf -h` against the binary to see if the ELF header has been corrupted
- A number of tools can parse such a binary, including radare2, Cutter, IDA, and Ghidra

Comment: How about those ones with `file` command output including:
"error reading (Invalid argument)"

Comment: @IWonder No idea. Use `readelf` with the `-h` option to look at the header, and then the `-l` option to look at section-to-segment mappings. If your are serious about getting help, share the output of the above commands in your post

Comment: Added in the comment

Comment: @IWonder looks like section information hasn’t been removed from the binary but readelf cannot parse the section header table. My guess is that the sh_off value is not correct. If this is the case you will need to manually inspect the binary to determine the correct section header table offset